# get last integer value from char array

Tags: c

Consider a char array like this:

```
43 234 32 32
```

I want the last value that is `32` in integer form.

The string size/length is not known. In the above example there are 4 numbers, but the size will vary.

How can this be done?

Comment: your question is unclear.  Do you want to convert the array of chars into an array of integer, or do you want to find the last valid entry in the array that has only numbers and convert it to an integer?

Comment: no i do not want an integer array i just want the last entry in an  integer variable

Comment: How do you know it is the last value in the array if the "size/length is not known"?  Is the end marked in some way?

Comment: sir that is the problem i dont know how much array is filled.each time it has different elements

Comment: i have copied these value from the file onto char array.now i want the last number in integer variable

Comment: Well, then you do know how many elements there are in the array because you read them from the file, right?

Comment: @Randy If you don't know how much of the array is filled up, it's impossible to determine the last value.  You could, theoretically, iterate over every element in the array and check to see if the character is a number, but you can't assume there won't be uninitialized garbage after the last "real" value.

Comment: If you don't know the size of the array, then how did you allocate memory for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no trailing whitespace on the line:

```
int last_int(const char *s)
{
    const char *ptr = strrchr(s, ' ');
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        ptr = s;
    } else {
        ptr++;
    }

    return atoi(ptr);
}
```

If there can be trailing whitespace, then you'll need to do something like what ProdigySim suggested, but with more states, to walk backwards past the trailing whitespace (if any), then past the number, then call atoi().  No matter what you do, you'll need to watch out for boundary conditions and edge cases and decide how you want to handle them.

Answer (score 3):

> *i have copied these value from the file onto char array.now i want the last number in integer variable*

When you were copying,add a counter of # of characters copied. Then do this

```
int count = 0;
char c;
while(c = readCharFromFile()) {
  array[count++] = c;
}

int last = array[count - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve this.

1. Convert every token (space delimited string) into a number and when the tokens run out return the last value converted.
2. Scan the line for tokens until you get to the end and then convert the last token into a number.
3. Start at the end of the line. Skip spaces and store digits until the first space is encountered and then convert the result to a number.
4. Split the string into an array of strings and convert the last one into a number.

I could go on and on but you get the idea I hope.

Answer (score 1):

```
int getLastInt(char *data)
{
    size_t i = strlen(data);
    if(!i--) return -1; // failure
    for(;i;--i)
    {
        if(data[i] == ' ')
        {
            return atoi(&data[i+1]);
        }
    }
    return -1; // failure
}
```

Should work as long as the data has a space + actual text.
You could also skip the strlen and just loop forward, which could be faster depending on your system's strlen.

Comment: strlen(data); assuming that the data is null terminated.

Comment: hi thanks so much for your help.but will i think i will return 23 instead of 32 thanks

Comment: @randy nope, it will return 32.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use a combination of strtok_r and atoi